# C++ - Calling the non default constructor in a nested template instantiation

Tags: c++

I'm currently working to instantiate an Array of Stacks of cards for a FreeCell implementation. Each of the Array, Stack, and Card classes are created by me, and the Stack and Array classes are templated.

```
Array<StackRA<Card>> * hometemp = new Array<StackRA<Card>>(4);
```

When this code runs, it instantiates an Array of size 4, as intended, but calls the default constructor on the Stack, which I need to instantiate to size 13.

I've tried the following:

```
Array<StackRA<Card>> * hometemp = new Array<StackRA<Card>(13)>(4)
Array<StackRA<Card>> * hometemp = new Array<StackRA<Card>13>(4)
```

The Stack's default constructor is as follows:

```
template <typename T>
StackRA<T>::StackRA() : m_stack()
{
    size = 0;
}
```

As well as the 1 arg constructor that I want to call

```
template <typename T>
StackRA<T>::StackRA( int data ) : m_stack( data )
{
    size = data;
}
```

I've tried my luck on Google, but it keeps leading me to resources on templates inside template classes. Any thoughts are appreciated.

EDIT: Stepping into my program leads to the Array constructor

```
template<class T>
Array<T>::Array(int length, int start_index)
{
    if (length < 0)
    {
        cout << "Length cannot be negative, length has been defaulted to 0\n";
        m_length = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        m_length = length;
        m_start_index = start_index;
        m_array = new T[length];
    }
}
```

The problem, more specifically, is that the "m_array = new T[length];" calls the StackRA default constructor. The question still stands, how can the non default constructor be called. Where in the instantiation would I place the size data I want to pass in?

EDIT2: I've solved this issue for this specific implementation using:

```
template <typename T>
StackRA<T>::StackRA() : m_stack()
{
    size = 13;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if `Array` represents an array, and is meant to be used like one, then you don't need to create a pointer. You can construct it as an automatic object:

```
Array<StackRA<Card>> hometemp(4);
```

Now the problem as you say is with the following code calling the default-constructor for each element in the array:

```
m_array = new T[length];
```

This is true, the default-constructor will be called, initializing each constructor as `T()`. Prior to C++11, it was not possible to initialize each element using a different constructor, but now you are able to initialize using an initializer-list:

```
m_array = new T[length] { T(13), T(13), ... };
```

Of course this wouldn't be preferable for a variable-sized array (or an array with a very large size), and it's not for our purposes. Instead, you can follow the behavior of `std::vector` and create another constructor that copies an object to each element in the array:

```
template <typename T>
StackRA<T>::StackRA(int size, const T& obj) : size(size), m_stack(/* ... */)
{
    m_array = new T[size];
    std::fill(m_array, m_array + size, obj);
}
```

Now when constructing the array you can pass the correct constructor:

```
Array<StackRA<Card>> hometemp(4, StackRA<Card>(13));
```

Comment: Last line, you must mean `Array<StackRA<Card>> hometemp(4, StackRA<Card>(13));`

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything special in your `Array` so you cannot use `std::vector`? With `std::vector`, you would simply say

```
std::vector<StackRA<Card>> * hometemp =
    new std::vector<StackRA<Card>>(4, StackRA<Card>(13));
```

Better, if the size is always fixed, use `std::array`, e.g.

```
std::vector<std::array<Card, 13>> * hometemp =
    new std::vector<std::array<Card, 13>>(4);
```

or

```
std::array<std::array<Card, 13>, 4> * hometemp =
    new std::array<std::array<Card, 13>, 4>();
```

or even

```
using Stack = std::array<Card, 13>;
using Deck  = std::array<Stack, 4>;
Deck *hometemp = new Deck();
```

If you want to add functionality, you can simply encapsulate standard library containers into your own types.

Also, you might reconsider your use of the free store and especially raw pointers:

```
Deck hometemp;
```

If you insist on your own implementations, you might have a look at [`std::vector` constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) for ideas.